# vim is really slow to start and slow to quit

Tags: vim, autocmd

Okay I need help. For some reason, vim has been really slow to start since a couple of days. I investigated this and I saw that it was probably because of my .vimrc file.

for instance here they suggest to put autocmd lines inside an augroup block.

https://superuser.com/questions/633790/how-to-speed-up-opening-vim-buffer

But the thing is that vim is also slow to save (i.e. write :w) file I'm editing and also slow (10-20 sec) to quite (:q).

Any help will be quite appreciated.

Here is my .vimrc file:

```
set nowrap
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set number
set bg=dark
set t_Co=256
:set expandtab
:set tabstop=3
:syntax enable
:colorscheme softblue
set backspace=indent,eol,start

augroup Perl
   autocmd!
   " Use perl compiler for all *.pl and *.pm files.
   autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.pl,*.pm compiler perl
augroup END

:map <F2> :set nonumber<CR>
:map <F3> :set number<CR>
:map <F4> :set nowrap<CR>
:map <F5> :set wrap<CR>
:map <F6> :%!column -t<CR>
:map <F7> :s/torque/batch/g<CR>
:map <F8> :s/batch/torque/g<CR>
:map <F9> :%s/\(---S\d\d\d\.\)\(\S\+_R\d\.fastq\.gz\)/\1\2  \2/gc<CR>
```

And my startup time log file. The problem seems to be in opening buffers.
    vim tmp.txt --startuptime startuptime.txt

```
times in msec
clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.012  000.012: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.164  000.152: Allocated generic buffers
000.375  000.211: locale set
000.404  000.029: GUI prepared
000.408  000.004: clipboard setup
000.420  000.012: window checked
001.497  001.077: inits 1
001.586  000.089: parsing arguments
001.588  000.002: expanding arguments
001.610  000.022: shell init
002.123  000.513: Termcap init
002.181  000.058: inits 2
002.310  000.129: init highlight
024.219  000.336  000.336: sourcing /gs/project/dmn-380-ab/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
024.488  001.158  000.822: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
048.830  023.810  023.810: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
048.990  026.275  001.307: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
049.957  000.276  000.276: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
050.923  000.272  000.272: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
051.838  000.271  000.271: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
052.054  002.943  002.124: sourcing /sb/home/user/.vim/colors/softblue.vim
052.303  030.128  000.910: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
052.320  019.882: sourcing vimrc file(s)
053.669  001.102  001.102: sourcing /sb/home/user/.vim/plugin/color_sample_pack.vim
057.634  000.170  000.170: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
058.252  000.396  000.396: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
058.778  000.297  000.297: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
059.732  000.720  000.720: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
060.111  000.125  000.125: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
060.453  000.109  000.109: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
061.703  000.290  000.290: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
062.141  000.194  000.194: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
062.659  000.290  000.290: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
063.303  000.339  000.339: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
063.467  007.115: loading plugins
063.491  000.024: inits 3
063.718  000.227: reading viminfo
063.961  000.243: setup clipboard
063.973  000.012: setting raw mode
064.005  000.032: start termcap
064.048  000.043: clearing screen
10698.690  000.801  000.801: sourcing /gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/scripts.vim
10699.429  10634.580: opening buffers
10699.466  000.037: BufEnter autocommands
10699.469  000.003: editing files in windows
10699.600  000.131: VimEnter autocommands
10699.602  000.002: before starting main loop
10699.971  000.369: first screen update
10699.973  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Comment: Is it slow for all stuff or only pl and pm files? 
I tried your .vimrc and it was as fast as usually ( but I wasn't editiing perl files and your colorscheme didn't load)

Comment: No it is slow for everything, not only .pm or .pl files.
Even if I remove the augroup block it still slow.

Comment: @JulienTremblay Did you modify the file `/gs/project/dmn/software/vim/vim-7.4/share/vim/vim74/scripts.vim`? According to the log Vim sources it at startup and that's what take an eternity to load. It seems that this script comes with the default installation, I'm not sure why it is so slow on your system.

Comment: @JulienTremblay Also the `:` prefixing your `set`, `colorscheme` and `map` commands are not necessary, but that is not what causes the slowness.

Comment: @JulienTremblay is it slow with an empty vimrc ?

Comment: @byaruhaf Seems to be faster with an empty .vimrc indeed... And no I did not modified the scripts.vim file in any ways

Comment: Well this is beyond me, it now works flawlessly. It had to have something to do with the filesystem... I'll see with the sys admins if that could have been the case. I just don't understand why it was slow to quit as well...